# How to view x86 Assembly from C program with .bin extension - Linux

Tags: assembly, x86, reverse-engineering

I am trying to view the x86 Assembly for a compiled C program in Linux, for which I do not have the source code. Can this be done with GCC, or do I need a different tool?  Thanks.

Comment: You really want to look into disassemblers for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GCC is a compiler.  What you're looking for is a disassembler.  On linux, you can use [`objdump(1)`](http://www.bigbiz.com/cgi-bin/manpage?1+objdump).

An example (some `objdump` output snipped for ease of reading):

```
$ cat example.c 
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("Hello, world!\n");
    return 0;
}
$ clang -Wall -Wextra -O2 -o example example.c
$ ./example 
Hello, world!
$ objdump -d example | grep -A10 '<main>'
0000000000400500 <main>:
  400500:   55                      push   %rbp
  400501:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  400504:   bf 0c 06 40 00          mov    $0x40060c,%edi
  400509:   e8 e2 fe ff ff          callq  4003f0 <puts@plt>
  40050e:   31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
  400510:   5d                      pop    %rbp
  400511:   c3                      retq   
  400512:   90                      nop
  400513:   90                      nop
  400514:   90                      nop
```

Answer (score 0):

objdump -d program > dumped.txt